# Is it possible to manage Wireguard from the pull-down menu?

Tags: notification-bar, vpn

I connect to my Wireguard endpoint with the official wireguard app. Everything works fine but in order to stop the VPN connection, I must find and restart the app.

Since the VPN activity is visible in the taskbar

[image]

... I was hoping for a way to quickly manage it from there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App description of [Wireguard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wireguard.android) shows a quick tile setting, which can be readily used!

[image]